# Compute $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 3^k {n \choose k}$

Tags: calculus

How can I compute it: $$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 3^k {n \choose k}$$

I tried used definition of Newton's Binomial but I have no idea what can I do next. Furthermore I checked that this isn't  geometric series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Use the binomial theorem after noticing that $$\sum_{k\ge 0}3^k\binom{n}k=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k3^k1^{n-k}\;.$$

Comment: So the correct answer is $4^n$. I'm very grateful for your help.

Comment: @user2213654: Yes, it is, and you’re very welcome.